# Amazon SQS or CloudAmqp or RabbitMq setup on EC2

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-sqs, cloudamqp

We have to implement a queuing system for our ROR Application.We have evaluated the following options:

Amazon SQS: High Availability but relatively slow performance.Requires constant poling.

CloudAmqp: Looks promising but doubtful about the support.

RabbitMq setup on EC2: Needs user bandwidth to manage the setup,may result in downtime if some issue arises in the setup.

Right now there won't be any dedicated team/person to manage the setup full-time so implementing our own RabbitMq setup on Ec2 may result in downtime in case something goes wrong.
I want to know considering the situation which is our best option?

Answer (score 5):

I use SQS and I am happy with it; I don't worry about the support aspect, because I also don't have time to deal with setting up my own server and supporting myself when I can pay AWS pennies to do it for me.

If you don't want to poll constantly, considering pairing up your SQS queue with an SNS topic and it can do push notifications to your application instead. Don't know the nature of your application, but its something to look into. http://aws.amazon.com/sns/

ALso keep in mind the slow performance of SQS (relative to Rabbit) is not apples to apples. SQS is redundant and distributed, a single instance of RabbitMQ on a single box is not; can your application deal with the queue not being available for a period of time?

Comment: Thanks! Availability is of prime importance so setting up our own Rabbitmq instance is not the best option right now. SQS with SNS looks interesting.

Comment: hi @E.J Brennan 
can you please answer my question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27315968/1254813

Answer (score 4):

At CloudAMQP all our servers are redundant, each cluster has at least two instances in different availability zones. For support we have email support 24/7, as we have staff in different timezones. We do have phone support for our largest plans too.

Comment: Thanks for the information! will definitely consider using Cloudamqp.